The idea of how to have password-protected filesystem for the Linux LiveOS
Our organization has a couple of servers across the country in the different datacenters (mainly they are dedicated Dells or HPs/Supermicros). These servers has the OS which is Ubuntu based (20.04/22.04). Also they contain some kind of proprietary software developed by our engineers which accepts the data inside the DC and then send to us for the analysis (logs/events/etc). The root filesystem is password-protected using dmcrypt. The kernel initramfs image also is built to contain the app which knocks to us for the unlock password if needed.
From other side we have a group of staff who travels across the country and maintain those servers once/per year-two... In order to do that, the main team prepares to them the LiveCD which they build on top of Ubuntu server. The process looks like:

debootstrap the minimum
install the utils for networking and debug (like ifenslave, tcpdump, etc...)
install service utils
install short-term certificates/keys for being able to grab the blobs/configs from our internal infra.
baking squashfs image
make an iso

The process looks like that:

The staff guy comes into the datacenter
inserts liveCD
invokes the prepared commands from the head office
downloads the licenses from our main infra using that liveCD
if everything is fine - reboots the server into the normal mode

And here is the question: is it possible to build the liveCD image in the way when the root filesystem would be encrypted like we have at the dedicated server? When the staff engineer boots from it - he/she enters rootfs password then the boot process continues to go. Right now the liveOS uses squashfs file to create it's root filesystem. Can we redo that somehow?

The livecd kernel's cmdline looks like this: BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed quiet splash --. I'd started to dig deeper into the boot scripts (there is a completely mess there :)) and found that I need to extend casper's boot process. By default it is not consider to use any cryptsetup logic and has its own way to find that squashfs file.
